# Using jenkins in a docker container with /var/jenkins_home on a NAS storage drive

Tags: docker, jenkins, nas

Im running ubuntu 18.04 with a NAS drive mounted via cifs.  I have pulled in the `jenkins:latest` image and have started it with this run command:

```
docker run --restart=unless-stopped --name devonejenkins -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v /mnt/storage/jenkins:/var/jenkins_home jenkins
```

That command doesn't work.  However, using a local disk on the vm, like this:

```
docker run --restart=unless-stopped --name devonejenkins -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v /home/chrisg/jenkins:/var/jenkins_home jenkins
```

seems to work just fine.

Without pasting a tonne of stacktrace code, this seems to be the failure point:

> SEVERE: Failed to initialize jenkins java.io.IOException: Failed to
>   set the timestamp of /var/jenkins_home/secrets/initialAdminPassword to
>   1547434033746

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you have mounted your cifs volume.

[This example](https://forums.docker.com/t/secrets-with-docker-volumes-in-compose/47527) refers to [`ContainX/docker-volume-netshare`](https://github.com/ContainX/docker-volume-netshare), a docker plugin which mounts NFS v3/4, AWS EFS or CIFS inside your docker containers.

An [older (2015) article](https://backdrift.org/docker-cifs-howto-mount-cifs-volume-docker-container) mentioned permission issues:

> The docker container will not be permitted to access your CIFS mount point unless you or mount the share with the appropriate SELinux security context.

And:

> Unlike NFS, a CIFS mount handles user authentication at mount time. This means that all files and directories at our CIFS mount point will be owned by the same user/group.
>   This may be a problem if the user of the process running in your container and the user of the CIFS mount are not the same.
>   I worked around this by mounting the same CIFS share multiple times with different uid and gid arguments.